# Getting MySQL Error when trying to insert data from text fields into database

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting this error when trying to insert data into my database from my website:

```
Error: INSERT INTO newtask (new_category, new_department, new_required, 
new_name, new_address, new_contact, new_email,  new_logged, new_description) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
?, 
?)' at line 1
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbname = 'tasks_db';


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO newtask (new_category, new_department, new_required, 
new_name, new_address, new_contact, new_email,  new_logged, new_description) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Not sure what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Do try and get out of the habit of cluttering up your code with needless things like `=== true`. Many functions are designed to return values that evaluate as logically true or false so that's redundant.

Comment: Where are the variables that are supposed to replace all the `?` placeholders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a prepared statement, so you need to prepare it, bind your values, and *then* execute it:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO newtask (new_category, new_department, new_required, 
new_name, new_address, new_contact, new_email,  new_logged, new_description) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

// One "s" per placeholder value, plus one value per "s" after
$stmt->bind_param("sssssssss", $new_category, $new_department, ...);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Where `$new_category` is whatever value is going into that column and so on.
This is all covered in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

The mistake is you were trying to run a SQL query with placeholder values and no data. `?` is not a valid value in MySQL. It's replaced at the driver level by the `bind_param` operation on statements produced with `prepare`. The `query` function executes code as-is with no changes.

Comment: Thanks,  now it makes a bit more sense.  However this is the error i am getting now 'Undefined variable: sql.... ' on line 25 which is 'echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later." . $sql ."<br>" . $conn->error;'

Comment: Since in this code `$sql` was factored out, just remove that from the `echo` statement. The connection error should contain any relevant details required to debug this. Note: Echoing raw errors in a production environment is an extremely risky practice. Try to log these instead.